# Tricky interview subject for C++

Tags: c++

Given the code below, how would you create/implement SR.h so that it produces the correct output WITHOUT any asterisks in your solution?

I got bummed by this question. I would like to know some of the different approaches that people use for this problem.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "SR.h"

int main()
{
    int j = 5;
    int a[] = {10, 15};
    {
        SR x(j), y(a[0]), z(a[1]);

        j = a[0];
        a[0] = a[1];
        a[1] = j;

        printf("j = %d, a = {%d, %d}\n", j, a[0], a[1]);
    }

    printf("j = %d, a = {%d, %d}\n", j, a[0], a[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
j = 10, a = {15, 10}
j = 5, a = {10, 15}
```

Second one:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "SR.h"
int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        SR ii(i);
        while (i--)
            sum += i;
    }
    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
}

//The output is "sum = 161700".
```

Comment: Why shouldn't this be a real question? Am I missing something?

Comment: @sbi Interview questions, particularly artificial ones, usually are not "real". Not that I downvoted or close voted this one myself.

Comment: I'm also unsure about the negative vote. Perhaps folks need to be quick these days.

Comment: FYI the answer should satisfy both test cases

Comment: This is indeed an EXCELLENT question, both for general knowledge and interview purposes.

Comment: @Kirill et al.: Given that three separate people came up with the correct answer within about twenty minutes of the question being posted, I'm confident that it could "be reasonably answered in its current form" :P .

Comment: Clearly it can be answered in its current form, as Bill did exactly that.  Voted to reopen.

Comment: "I saw in an interview..." seems to be the best way to hide homework or quiz questions

Comment: not a real question... editing has gone to hell in the past year.

Comment: @Neil: Call me conservative, but to me a question seems "real" when it comes in the form of a grammatical question (i.e., something you can put a question mark after), poses a problem, and, in theory, allows allows you to write up something which answers it. Whether it is "artificial" (whatever that means - wouldn't almost all homework questions be artificial?) seems subjective to me, the criteria I gave seems objective.

Comment: @chris been here since beta, questions were much worse then

Comment: @Sean - I won't argue that things have been gotten better, perhaps as a result of the overzealous close-modders, but apparently the modding has worked, as this question has been "unclosed."  It would be better if SO still let you comment on something even if it were closed.  I can't tell you the number of times I've been writing an extensive answer to something only to find out that the question had been closed.  It pisses me off, and this example, I think, shows exactly why the close-modders need to be put on ice.

Comment: What solution/approach is the phrase "WITHOUT any asterisks in your solution" trying to negate?  I could only think of the reference-saving-restore solution that everyone else suggested... what is the pointer-based "short-cut" answer that I assume the asker is trying to avoid receiving?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

SR is acting as a captured-variable-restorer.  When it goes out of scope it restores some value that it previously captured.

The constructor will do two things: capture a reference, and capture the value of that reference.  The destructor will restore the original value to that reference.

```
class SR
{
public:
  SR(int& var) : capture(var), value(var) {}
  ~SR() { capture = value; }

private:
  int& capture;
  int value;
};
```

Edit: Just a guess, but I assume SR is supposed to stand for ScopeRestorer?

Comment: My thought was SR = SaveRestore.

Answer (score 16):

I don't have time to write code but, you need to use references &int in constructor. And you would need to restore original values to references in the destructor. When SR goes out of scope it needs to restore original values that were passed in during construction.

Answer (score 4):

For the first one:

```
class SR
{
    int &ref;
    int orig;
public:
    SR(int& r)
    :ref(r), orig(r)
    {
    }

    ~SR()
    {
        ref = orig;
    } 
};
```

For the second snippet, should it be the same SR or some other SR?

Comment: This solution works for both, so I assume it's meant to satisfy both `main` functions.

Comment: Hey!, what I have learnt is reference should be initalise while declaring so how is this different, does constructor works in a different way?

Answer (score 4):

```
#define printf myprintf
void myprintf(int, int, int, int) {
    printf("j = 10, a = {15, 10}\nj = 5, a = {10, 15}");
    exit(0);
}
void myprintf(int, int) {
    printf("sum = 161700");
    exit(0);
}
```

Or, in other words, I think the concept of the scope restorer macro is really cool, but I don't like the way the question was worded :)

Comment: haha, funny! This could actually be a smart ass answer for this problem.

Comment: I'm almost tempted to start a bounty and give it to you.

Answer (score 2):

Solution to first question

```
class SR
{
public:
int initial;
int* var;
SR(int &a) : var(&a),initial(a){}

~SR()
{
    *var = initial;
}
};
```

Comment: I don't know who has downvoted, but i've restored the ballance, since for me it's actually easier code to read in this instance. You know what you are saving (an address to a pointer). Reference values are cool, but this doesn't make this answer wrong.

Comment: thanks @Volodya   yes i agree user should use references where they can be used instead pointers. I used pointers just like that ,no particular reasons, my focus was to solve the problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A solution to #2 is:

```
#define _SR_H_

int count = 0;

class SR {
private:
    int& ref;
public:
    SR(int& val) : ref(val) {
        count++;
    }
    ~SR() {
        if (count == (161700 + 1)) {
            ref = 100;
        } else {
            ref = 1;
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

I know this solution is a bit ugly, and it runs the `for` loop 161700 times to add the numbers. This would work for any number, but I am not sure why 161700 was chosen. It doesn't factorize nicely either.

Comment: This "answer" should be deleted as completelly misleading. The same SRT class works here as well. the effect is as if you had int k=i, while (k--) sum += k;

Same applies to the one bellow caliming to be "special for #2".

Answer (score -1):

very very ugly answer to second question ==>

```
class SR
{
public:
int* var;
int initial;
SR(int &a) : var(&a)
{
    initial = *var;
    if (1 == *var)
    {
        *var = 569;
    }
    else if (2 == *var)
    {
        *var = 5;
    }
    else if ((99 == *var) || (98 == *var) || (97 == *var ))
    {
        *var = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        *var = 2;
    }
}

~SR()
{
        *var = initial;
}
};
```